# Shuffling different parts of nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, nested, each

I'm attempting to build a multiple-choice quiz which will not only shuffle the four answer options each time but also shuffle the order that the questions appear each time the user takes the same quiz.

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
function fisherYates(myArray) {
var i = myArray.length, j, tempi, tempj;
if (i === 0) return false;
while (--i) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    tempi = myArray[i];
    tempj = myArray[j];
    myArray[i] = tempj;
    myArray[j] = tempi;
}
}
$(function() {
    content = [
        ["Q1",["Q1-1", "Q1-2", "Q1-3", "Q1-4"]], 
        ["Q2",["Q2-1", "Q2-2", "Q2-3", "Q2-4"]], 
        ["Q3",["Q3-1", "Q3-2", "Q3-3", "Q3-4"]]
    ];

    $.each(content, function(i) { fisherYates(this) });
    fisherYates(content);
})
```

This shuffles the questions, but I see that I also need to go one step deeper to shuffle the options nested under each question value. I have limited understanding of how `$.each()` works and how to get this to run within the nested arrays.

The vital thing is that the resulting array should not separate the shuffled options from the question they are associated with.

Not sure if nested arrays are the right way to go about this rather than using a hash (although the clue may lie in the fact that I just used the word "associated" in that last paragraph!)

TIA

Comment: How about `{fisherYates(this); fisherYates(this[1])}`?

Comment: although I upvoted this, I thought it was the same as Bartek Suski's solution below. I didn't read it carefully enough. When I applied this, the questions appeared after the options in the resulting array. Not a big deal but not exactly what I want the output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shuffles questions with answer tables. You just need to go one level deeper inside the each function.

```
$(function() {
    content = [
        ["Q1",["Q1-1", "Q1-2", "Q1-3", "Q1-4"]], 
        ["Q2",["Q2-1", "Q2-2", "Q2-3", "Q2-4"]], 
        ["Q3",["Q3-1", "Q3-2", "Q3-3", "Q3-4"]]
    ];

    $.each(content, function(i) { fisherYates(this[1]) });
    fisherYates(content);
});
```

Comment: yes, that's more elegant than the `for` loop I was running when I edited `content` to `content[i]` to solve it an alternative way